# Explain the KeyListener in Java

Tags: java, awt, ui-automation, keylistener

I am someone new to Java and working with the robot class. I would like to make an emergency stop function for my robot so when it does something wrong I can make the automation end. While robot so far has been easy the key listener escapes me, please explain in a "my first keylistener" style, thank you!
Here is what I have so far:

```
public static void keyboard(String input, HWND window) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Keyboard Typing:\n" + input);
        //This is just to stop the error, but I don't know how
        //to actually listen
        KeyEvent e = null;  
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {;
            keepFocus(window);
            if(stopBot(e /*How to pass a key press*/) == true){
                break;
            }
            char c = input.charAt(i);
            keyboardHandler(c);
            Thread.sleep(80);
        }
    }

    public static boolean stopBot(KeyEvent e){
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_END){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

There is other code but this is all that is relevant to my problem

Comment: *"please explain in a "my first keylistener" style"* SO is not a tutorial service. Do you have a (specific) question?

Comment: A lot of other questions I've looked at similar to mine have been:
"here you go: (code here)"
I want to understand the code not just copy paste and cross my fingers @AndrewThompson

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I could think about implementing a key event is by making your current class extend a Key Listener class. Basically, you want your current class to be listening for keystrokes in the background. You'll start by adding the implementation to your class name:

```
public YourClassName implements KeyListener {
}
```

Now, your class is able to listen for key strokes in the background. You'll now need to add a listener in your code and then give it instructions on what to do when hit. You'll add the listener by invoking the following method:

```
this.addKeyListener()
```

You can also replace "this" with any other instantiated object capable of handling action events. Now, you just need to be able to instruct the program on what to do when the listener picks up a key stroke event. The key listener will evoke one method from the KeyListener class you are extending: keyPressed(KeyEvent e), keyRelease(KeyEvent e), or keyTyped(KeyEvent e). These are the functions that will then run whatever code you'd like when a key-event is picked up and passed through the function. You will need to override these methods like so:

```
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        //whatever you want to happen in the case of 
        this event, I assume stop your robot
}
```

So, as you can see, you don't need to worry about invoking your own KeyEvent, Java's addKeyListener will take care of this as long you've extended the class and given instructions on what to do for each event! Hope this helps!

Comment: By extends do you mean implements? I'm getting an error from extends saying to change to implements or make my class an interface.
Also where to call this.addKeyListener() it seems to error saying it can't be called statically?

Comment: I'm so sorry-- I totally did! Let me edit that. It cannot be called from a static context, and you should add it to whatever object you are listening for a key in. If it is in the same class you pasted, you simply need to set it up anytime before you want to listen for a key stroke.  If you're having trouble putting it in a non-static context you might consider making your class implement Runnable or maybe an object without a main class.

Comment: Ok so now it's no longer static but Java is not recognizing .addKeyListener() when I instantiate the object implementing the keylistener

Comment: try instead 'addKeyListener(this)'